# Initialize a git repository remotely

Tags: git, github

I have a scenario wherin I want to initialize a git repo remotely on type of the command `git init`.

Now when I do a `git init`, it creates a repository in the current directory.
But what I want to do is, I want to create a create a git repo remotely.

Something like git init

I dont want to a git init and then do a git push.

Is it possible?

Comment: do git init on the remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an `ssh otherhost git init /path/to/repo`.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to the remote server, create a new directory and initialize it:

```
mkdir new_repo.git
cd new_repo.git
git init --bare
```

Make sure you configure permissions correctly if needed, then just set your local working repo's remote to the server address.

Take a look at [this](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/) for the difference between `git init` and `git init --bare`.